# How to choose class's operator== overloading over the template operator==?

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, operator-overloading

I have overloaded the `operator==` for several types, using both template and in-line class method. But when come to the reference of an object as the `lhs`. The template `operator==` overloading will be used. Why not the `operator==` overloaded in the class definition?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T0, typename T1>
bool operator==(const T0& lhs, const T1& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Template == " << std::endl;
    return true;
}

struct Obj
{
    std::int32_t a;
    bool operator==(const Obj& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Obj == " << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

bool cmp(const Obj& obj) { return (obj == Obj{ 1 }); }

int main() {
    Obj a{ 2 };
    const Obj& b = a;
    cmp(a);
    cmp(b);
    a == b;
    b == a;
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the following results:

```
Template ==
Template ==
Obj ==
Template ==
```

Is it possible to force the compiler using the overloading defined inside the class?

Comment: Your member `operator==` isn't a `const` member function and cannot be called with a `const Obj` as its left hand side.

Comment: I really hope your actual template function isn't as broad as you have showed it here. Also, you can (and should) make the `Obj::operator==` function `const`.

Comment: Because you haven't quliafied the member function as `const`, so the template version is a better match.   Try `bool operator==(const Obj &rhs) const {return true;};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to force the compiler using the overloading defined
> inside the class?

**Yes**, simply make the `operator==` overload a `const` qualified function, so that it will act on the `const` object of `Obj`.

```
bool operator==(const Obj& rhs) const /* noexcept */
{
    std::cout << "Obj == \n";
    return a == rhs.a; // meaningful comparison
}
```

It chooses the template overload because it was the best match, which takes the `const` object.

As a side note, provide a  meaningful comparison, something like above. [See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G1bhEn46T)